# Basic 3 grid layout html/css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So basically I need to create a 3 grid layout which looks like:

```
 -------------------------------------
|  Image  | The name of logo      | > |
 -------------------------------------
```

I have somewhat do this with :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="card-header">
      <a class="card-link row" href="/webview/topup">
        <p style="font-size: 14sp; margin-bottom: 0">
          <img src="../images.png" th:src="@{../images/image.png}" width="10%" 
            height="10%" style="vertical-align: middle; font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;">
          The name of logo 
          <img src="../arrow.png" th:src="@{../arrow.png}" width="2%" height="2%"
           style="vertical-align: middle;" align="right";>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But somehow my arrow is not centered because it only uses align right. How can I make my arrow to be **align right and centered** at the same time?

Im sorry to ask such basic questions, because Im kinda new to html/css. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods to achieve this.

You can use flexbox on the parent:

```
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

and add:

```
{
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

to the last child. In your example, the arrow.

A good visual introduction/overview of flexbox is available here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

A concrete example of this with your code:

```css
.card-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.arrow {
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.logo {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="card-header">
  <a class="card-link row" href="/webview/topup">
    <img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <p class="text">The name of logo </p>
    <img class="arrow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> This can be done using css "grid" or "flex". You can refer to many
>   articles related to 'css flex' and 'css grid'. You can easily align
>   items in both vertical and horizontal. And there are many ways to align items inside a grid. This will be suitable for your case.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>Image</div> 
  <div>The name of logo</div>
  <div>></div>  
</div>
```